# Arranging grid using isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using Jquery isotope to arrange divs of different sizes.

When the html is this:

```
<div id="feed">
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>     
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>                 
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>     
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>      
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>
</div>
```

The grid arranges nicely :
[image]

But when I change the html to this:

```
<div id="feed">
    <div class="item size2">
    </div>     
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>                 
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>     
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>      
    <div class="item size1">
    </div>
</div>
```

The grid looks like this:
[image]

The `feed` div is `540px` wide, but I want the width to be used completely before more rows can be filled, its not happening in the 2nd case.

The jquery looks like this:

```
$('#feed').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem got resolved by providing a finite value for the property `columnWidth`like this:

```
$('#container').isotope({
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 240
  }
});
```

More [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html).